# Problem with relativity of acceleration

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation

In this answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/92833/36977 John said that acceleration is not relative in the general theory of relativity.

But as we all know, accelerating charges emit electromagnetic waves. So consider me and a charged body. Suppose acceleration is relative. Then if I accelerate, from my reference frame the charged body is accelerating, and thus would emit electromagnetic radiation. But if the charged body and I are both at rest and then start accelerating with the same acceleration $a$ in the same direction relative then, from my perspective it won't be accelerating since it's acceleration is the same as mine. But the charged body is accelerating. So it must emit radiation. But, as I understand it, that means I shouldn't see that radiation because from my perspective it is at rest.

Is there a contradiction here?

Comment: Quick correction: I said acceleration is absolute in special relativity but not in general relativity.

Comment: So ok, by special relativity a charged body wont emit electromagnetic waves so if it is in the same situation as in my case? @JohnRennie

Comment: You can feel your own acceleration (the g-force you experience) with an [accelerometer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerometer). So you can deduce that you are accelerating, and that therefore the charged body must be accelerating as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does a charged particle accelerating in a gravitational field radiate?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21830/)

Comment: @Pulsar But from my reference frame, the particle wont be accelerating since it wouldn't be moving from my frame of referance

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your reference frame is not inertial so you can't apply the physics valid for an inertial system. A charge accelerating with respect to an inertial system radiates according to Maxwell's equations, which are valid for an inertial system. You just can't simply apply Maxwell's equation in a non-inertial frame.